# How to migrate physical server to VMware VM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

Using vSphere Client version 6.7, I need to create a new VM that will replace physical server.
I'm not sure where to start, I mean, should I create a new virtual switch? Newtork Interface Card? what should I ask myself when approaching to this project?
I tried google search shows only VMware converter manuals.
Please help with guides or any direction to let me study it well

Comment: Sorry to be brutally honest here but you need some help from someone who knows at least the basics, and that's not you. If you just continue to blunder ahead on your own you'll either make serious mistakes or at best have to re-do the work again as your knowledge expands. If the requirement is urgent then just pay someone with experience to help, if it's not urgent get on some courses, read some documentation and ideally get a mini version of your production systems to learn on and break without impacting production.

Comment: "I'm not sure where to start, I" - Read the manual? I mean, this is a standard operation and I am QUITE sute that the documentation has P2V conversions (physical to virtual) documents in extension and there are tools for that. So, you tell me you do not rear your documentation? Instead of google search - look at the table of contents.

Comment: Friends, sometimes it is better to save words, a fact that could have given me a good answer with a solution. See batistuta09's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

follow the steps:

0. ensure, that at least one NIC of ESXi is connected to same physical network as physical server (it is not necessary, but helps avoid network reconfiguration).
1. create a virtual switch with VM port group, which uses NIC connected to physical network.

   Detailed guide - https://geek-university.com/vmware-esxi/create-standard-switches/
2. P2V a physical machine with one of convertors - https://www.vmwareblog.org/v2v-converters-overview/

Comment: That was the problem! Ididn't saw the NIC, thanks man, networking team created that for me.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare converter is what you want if you are using VMWare.  That is the tool that does p2v (physical to virtual) migrations in the VMWare world. See the articles below.

https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html 
https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCenter-Converter-Standalone/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your respond, i'm trying to do it manually, create a new VM with the resources, but i don't know how to connect the VM  to the same subnet that the physical server is connected to, there is no adapter in vSphere which connected to this subnet.